# Flutter Hive - best way to manage saved data

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I need some guidance with Flutter Hive. I'm making an application for salesman which needs a cached data all the time, because he might go to places with no internet connection. At first attemp I used sqflite, but then I found out about Hive and that it's way faster than sqflite. So I give it a try.

**QUESTIONS/PROBLEMS**

1. How to clear/remove specific box or all of them to create them again?

`await Hive.deleteBoxFromDisk` - works very wird. One time I got everything twice or more. I need that, because I'm trying to give a button that will synchronize all the data manually. I also need that for automatical synchronization in background. I don't know which element changed, got removed or added, so the easiest way is to remove whole box and create it again with new data.

2. Elements customization

The `Customer` is a card with 4 `Text` widgets. Each widget may contain different information base on user configuration:

[image]

You can select an item, a change it's "value". When I save that, everything is working fine, but when go back, change one item and save again it's giving me:

`HiveError (HiveError: The same instance of an HiveObject cannot be stored in two different boxes.)`

I'm doing it like this:

```dart
  Future saveSelectedElements(List<CustomerElement> selectedElements) async {
    await Hive.deleteBoxFromDisk(CustomerCardCustomization.boxName);
    var box = await Hive.openBox<CustomerElement>(boxName);
    await box.addAll(selectedElements);
  }
```

**SUMMARY**

All those problems are, probably, based on my unexperience with the library and removing boxes and creating them again is not a good idea, I assumed. I tried Flutter long time ago and this project is an upgrade of that, old, first attempt.

The next step will be documents with autosave fuctionality using Hive and I'm already scared of it...

#FLUTTER DOCTOR

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928], locale pl-PL)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.50.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
```